# How to trigger Jenkins job using particular build number

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

for example
job name=ABC->build count {1,2,3} and want to trigger 1 then how trigger them using remote api in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdoYt.png)Jenkins in the image how to trigger 9th build using remote api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by you want to trigger build 9?
In Jenkins you cannot trigger old builds.  Once a build has completed it is logged and that is it.

Running a new build of that job would create build 11 next but it would follow the exact same build steps as build 9 unless you have changed any of the build configuration.

It might be worth editing your question to explain the rationale behind what you are trying to do and why and people might be able to point you in the right direction

Comment: Yes I want to redeployment the previous docker  using Jenkins remote API if next build when created docker then some functionality problem revert it in the previous docker version

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger an old build in Jenkins you trigger the particular stage of build using Jenkins console and API. other than you create some frontend page above the Jenkins to store the build version so you trigger the particular stage, not a Jinkins old build number.